# values from lexer are showing up in parser one value after expected one

Tags: parsing, bison

I am just starting out with using bison and am having trouble figuring out the behaviour. In a simple example, I have the string "{header: {version: 2, type: 4}}" that I am trying to parse. I need to extract the values 2 and 4 from the string. When I have the rules defined as

```
line_test: T_OPEN_BRACE T_HEADER T_OPEN_BRACE expression T_COMMA expression T_CLOSE_BRACE T_CLOSE_BRACE /* (rule 1) */
;

expression: T_VERSION T_NUMBER { printf("returned %d\n", $1); } /* (rule 2) */
      | T_TYPE T_NUMBER    { printf("returned %d\n", $1); }     /* (rule 3) */
;
```

what I get is that at the printf at the 2nd Rule T_NUMBER evaluates to 0 and at the printf at the 3rd Rule T_NUMBER evaluates to 2, meaning that the values somehow are shifted from the appropriate values they are supposed to be.

If I change the rules to be

```
line_test: T_OPEN_BRACE T_HEADER T_OPEN_BRACE expression T_COMMA expression T_CLOSE_BRACE T_CLOSE_BRACE /* (rule 1) */
;

expression: T_VERSION number /* (rule 2) */
          | T_TYPE number    /* (rule 3) */
;

number: T_NUMBER { printf("returned %d\n", $1); } /* rule 4 */
;
```

then the printf at the 4th rule is evaluated correctly both times, it first shows up 2, then 4. I looked at the state output of bison, and it all makes sense. My question is, why does this unexpected behaviour for the first set of Grammar rules happen? I can post my lexer or the full parser code, or even the bison state output if relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule/action:

```
expression: T_VERSION T_NUMBER { printf("returned %d\n", $1); }
```

prints the number associated with the token `T_VERSION`.  Since you probably don't set yylval in the lexer when you return `T_VERSION`, it's getting whatever value happens to be there.  You probably want:

```
expression: T_VERSION T_NUMBER { printf("returned %d\n", $2); }
```

which prints the value associated with the `T_NUMBER` token

Comment: gotcha, thanks for the help! I was thinking that the $# refers to the token that has a value associated with it for some reason. now it makes sense why bison was gripping at me that I need to define a %type for T_VERSION and T_TYPE.